# Mysql Connection failed due to database not found

Tags: java, mysql

```
 DB_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localHost:3306/test_DB";
```

When I debug the program an exception occurs that the `test_DB` does not exist. Is it possible to create the database when the query executes?

Comment: The question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to connect to the server, rather than the specific database:

```
DB_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localHost:3306/";
```

And then use `CREATE SCHEMA` to add the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about jdbc, but usually you can connect without specifying a database at all, then check if it exists and execute a `USE test_db` if it does, create it if it does not.

Often you'll see simply `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_db`... and then `USE test_db` (i.e. eliminate the need to explicitly check for existence)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you must create the database called 'test_DB' after connecting the database with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing your query check if the database exist or not , do something like

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root","root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
        DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = meta.getCatalogs();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String listofDatabases=rs.getString("TABLE_CAT");
            list.add(listofDatabases);
        }
        if(list.contains(database)){
        System.out.println("Database already exists");
```

if not write query to create database.. like

```
String database = DATABASENAME; // "nlshriraam";//bf.readLine();
st.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE "+database);
```

then execute your query..